# Using column as tiebreaker for maximums in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Reposted with clarification.

I am working on a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
+-------+----+------+------+
| Value | ID | Date | ID 2 |
+-------+----+------+------+
|     1 |  5 | 2012 | 111 |
|     1 |  5 | 2012 | 112 |
|     0 | 12 | 2017 | 113 |
|     0 | 12 | 2022 | 114 |
|     1 | 27 | 2005 | 115 |
|     1 | 27 | 2011 | 116 |
+-------+----+------+-----+
```

Only using rows with "Value" == "1" ("value is boolean), I would like to group the dataframe by ID and input the string "latest" to new (blank) column, giving the following output:

```
+-------+----+------+------+-------+
| Value | ID | Date | ID 2 |Latest |
+-------+----+------+------+-------+
|     1 |  5 | 2012 | 111 |        |
|     1 |  5 | 2012 | 112 | Latest |
|     0 | 12 | 2017 | 113 |        |
|     0 | 12 | 2022 | 114 |        |
|     1 | 27 | 2005 | 115 |        |
|     1 | 27 | 2011 | 116 | Latest |
+-------+----+------+-----+--------+
```

I am using the following code to find the maximum:

```
latest = df.query('Value==1').groupby("ID").max("Year").assign(Latest = "Latest")
df = pd.merge(df,latest,how="outer")
df
```

But I have since realized some of the max years are the same, i.e. there could be 4 rows, all with max year 2017. For the tiebreaker, I need to use the max ID 2 within groups.

```
latest = df.query('Value==1').groupby("ID").max("Year").groupby("ID 2").max("ID 2").assign(Latest = "Latest")
df = pd.merge(df,latest,how="outer")
df
```

but it is giving me a dataframe completely different than the one desired.

Comment: Groupby, within groups, sort values (with your tiebreakers), then pick the first item.

Comment: I am a complete amateur in Python, what do you mean by "within groups"? Is that a function? Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way a bit similar to your own approach. Basically, `groupby` + `last` to get the latest + `assign` a variable + `merge`:

```
df = df.merge(df.groupby(['ID', 'Value'])['ID 2'].last().reset_index().assign(Latest=lambda x: np.where(x['Value'], 'Latest', '')), how='outer').fillna('')
```

or even this works:

```
df = df.query('Value==1').groupby('ID').last('ID 2').assign(Latest='Latest').merge(df, how='outer').fillna('')
```

Output:

```
   Value  ID  Date  ID 2  Latest
0      1   5  2012   111        
1      1   5  2012   112  Latest
2      0  12  2017   113        
3      0  12  2022   114        
4      1  27  2005   115        
5      1  27  2011   116  Latest
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
df['Latest'] = np.where(df['ID2'].eq(df.groupby(df['Value'].ne(df['Value'].shift(1)).cumsum())['ID2'].transform('max')) & df['Value'].ne(0), 'Latest', '')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   Value  ID  Date  ID2  Latest
0      1   5  2012  111        
1      1   5  2012  112  Latest
2      0  12  2017  113        
3      0  12  2022  114        
4      1  27  2005  115        
5      1  27  2011  116  Latest
```

Comment: Is there a way to use this using `df.query()`? I apologize for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one with window functions:

```
c = df['Value'].ne(df['Value'].shift()) 
s = df['Date'].add(df['ID 2']) #add the year and ID for handling duplicates
c1 = s.eq(s.groupby(c.cumsum()).transform('max'))& (df['Value'].eq(1))

df['Latest'] = np.where(c1,'Latest','')
```

---

```
print(df)

   Value  ID  Date  ID 2  Latest
0      1   5  2012   111        
1      1   5  2012   112  Latest
2      0  12  2017   113        
3      0  12  2022   114        
4      1  27  2005   115        
5      1  27  2011   116  Latest
```